# Maven: package org.junit does not exist even though it is declared in dependencies list in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

We get this error and have searched other SO questions without luck. Our `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

but we still get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project android: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/sjain68/zxing/android/src/test/java/com/google/zxing/client/android/ReverseGeocoderTest.java:[3,17] package org.junit does not exist
```

Note that the class is under `src/test/java` as pointed out by other answers to this problem.

Comment: I suppose you have defined the dependency in dependencyManagement block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out... your source is in `src/test/java` but the goal being executed here is `compiler:compile` as would be used building your actual source opposed to `compiler:testCompile` for building your tests. See the documentation of the maven-compiler-plugin about these two different goals: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

I suspect something (configuration, bad plugin, something) is adding src/test/java to the build path... or changing the build directory... it's unfortunately been a while since I've personally done maven, but that seems to be the mismatch here.

Comment: Thanks. Bad configuration was the problem. Under our build section we had <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> so the test code was also being compiled as part of compiler:compile. Your answer gave us the hint to solve the problem.